# What does it mean to take the Laplace transform of a non-periodic position function?

Tags: physics, laplace-transform, mathematical-physics

What I'm trying to get through my head here is how taking the Laplace transform of a system with a position function like

$X(t)=t$

is possible.

To my current (admittedly incomplete) understanding, what a Laplace transform is doing to a system physically is defining it in terms of its frequency based on its time function.  However, the frequency of a system is defined as the number of cycles it goes through in a given amount of time, and if its position function looks like the above one (or any non-periodic function of $t$) I don't see how it's possible to define it in terms of frequency, and yet the transform of such a system is given as:

$L[X(t)]=\frac{1}{s^2}$

If anyone could explain this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This page on wave packets might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet   Here you can see localized traveling waves decomposed into their fourier transform.  The fourier transform (very closely related) is just a combination of periodic functions as well.